# How to validate boolean configuration value while using Options Pattern in ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

```json
"Foobar": {
        "Baz": "invalid-boolean-value"
    }
```

```cs
public record FoobarOptions
{
    public required bool Baz { get; init; }
}
```

```cs
public class FoobarOptionsSetup : IConfigureOptions<FoobarOptions>
{
    public const string SectionName = "Foobar";

    public FoobarOptionsSetup(IConfiguration configuration) : base(configuration)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(FoobarOptions options)
    {
        Configuration
            .GetSection(SectionName)
            .Bind(options);
    }
}
```

In this scenario `Configure` method of the `FoobarOptionsSetup` wont throw any exception and value of the `FoobarOptions.Baz` was false (default boolean value)

So I decided to mark it as nullable like that:

```cs
public record FoobarOptions
{
    public required bool? Baz { get; init; }
}
```

Even then the value of Baz is false.

I want to implement also `IValidateOptions<FoobarOptions>` but how I could even validate it when it has false value. I have to know if this is default value or it is just expected value from ENV variables or from the appsettings.

Only one way I see that I could manually receive this value from `IConfiguration`, try parse it with `bool.TryParse()` and/or compare its value to the one that `FoobarOptions.Baz` has.
I would want to avoid such solution because I am implementing this `IConfigureOptions` and `IValidateOptions` to avoid implementing my own ones.

How could I validate it?

Comment: What is the desired behavior, an exception on start or a null value?

Comment: I think you have to resort to using `GetValue` (`Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`) - `configuration.GetValue<bool?>("", null);` simply check for `null`

Comment: Just use in Startup `services.Configure<FoobarOptions>(option => configuration.GetSection(SectionName).Bind(option));`. You should get an exception on start if the bool value is not convertible (tested).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check options on start and throw exception, you can make hosted service (this runs on start) and inject options inside. Then you just need to access option value and it will try to convert section to object it is binded to. If convertion fails, exception is thrown.

```
public class OptionsCheckerHostedService : IHostedService
{


    public OptionsCheckerHostedService(IOptions<FoobarOptions> foobarOptions)
    {
        if (foobarOptions.Value is null)
        {
            throw new Exception("foobarOptions - SECTION NOT SET PROPERLY");
        }
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }



    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```